# Cannot seem to scroll full width of side push menu

Tags: html, css, viewport-units

I have created a side push menu which comes in from the right of the screen, however I am trying to make it usable at smaller screen sizes.

To do this I have started off by giving it a `min-height` and using `overflow: auto;` - so if users screens are too small they will see a scroll.

However, in testing it seems the menu scroll doesn't allow you to scroll to the bottom of the menu.

**CodePen:** http://codepen.io/gutterboy/pen/PPVjNO

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="page-wrap">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <header class="col-sm-12">
          <button id="toggle-menu">Toggle Menu</button>
        </header>
      </div>
      <div class="main-wrap row">
        <div id="content" class="content col-sm-10">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>

  <p>Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>

  <p>Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.</p>

  <p>Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus.</p>

  <p>Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>
        </div>
        <aside class="sidebar col-sm-2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu pellentesque purus. Nulla placerat at ligula non ultrices. Fusce posuere, augue eget porta scelerisque, felis magna malesuada ligula, sit amet fermentum diam neque a velit. Suspendisse volutpat nec justo at eleifend. Quisque eu efficitur augue. Mauris sapien metus, scelerisque vel egestas vel, accumsan in tortor. Integer ultrices feugiat dui, et ultricies orci tristique non. Vestibulum scelerisque metus sed cursus rhoncus. Proin dictum malesuada enim, ac maximus odio sollicitudin sed. Donec sollicitudin porta nisi quis venenatis. Vivamus elementum sem ac nisl tincidunt pretium. Pellentesque blandit fringilla mi, et eleifend lectus vulputate ut. Etiam rutrum, elit eu tincidunt commodo, odio justo pretium dui, non efficitur arcu libero in sapien. In placerat convallis tortor eu egestas. 
        </aside>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <nav class="main">
      <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Child Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Child Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Child Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Child Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Child Item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Child Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Child Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Child Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Child Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Child Item</a></li>
            </ul>            
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Clients</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Child Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Child Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Child Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Child Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Child Item</a></li>
            </ul>            
        </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>  

</div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
$menu-width: 300px;

header {

  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  height: 57px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #0B093C;
  z-index: 2;

  button {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
  }

}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-wrap {
   position: relative;
   left: 0;
   margin-top: 57px;
   transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;

  .menu-open & {
    left: -$menu-width;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
  }

}

.content {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #827FB2;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar {

  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #363377;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

nav.main {

  position: fixed;
  top: 57px;
  right: -$menu-width;
  width: $menu-width;
  height: calc(100vh - 57px);
  min-height: 500px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #0B093C;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 2000;

  .menu-open & {
    right: 0;
  }

  li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
  }

}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#toggle-menu').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    $('.wrapper').toggleClass('menu-open');

  });

});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: sorry I could not get the problem. The problem statements says scroll full width... but you tried by min-height? I am missing something?

Comment: @user2181397 Make your browser less than 500px in height and then you will see a secondary scroll for the menu you toggle in; if you use the scroll you won't be able to reach the bottom of the menu.

Comment: Change  this property min-height: 500px; of nav.main to max-height:some value and check

Comment: @user2181397 That doesn't really help. I don't want to set a max height on it, just a min-height.